# Recovery - Restore Database after moving folder location locally

Tags: database, mysql, localhost

I made a bit of an error over the weekend.

I moved the local installation of XAMPP and subsequently broke my entire local dev Wordpress install.

I have all of the folders intact from XAMPP including the SQLDatabase (mysql) and all WP-Content
Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the site operational as the drive directory has changed entirely and it cannot be moved back.

I do not have an export of my database, only the local database files

Am I able to restore the broken directory links in any way?
I can boot XAMPP but all the database links are broken

All files are hosted on my local device so no managed hosts or anything

Comment: As long as you have the same version of the database installed you can hopefully just drop the database files into that and have it work. I think that's your first step: once you've got that working please let us know what WordPress-specific problems you're still got. In general WordPress should be independent of its install location, unless you've got hard-coded paths in wp-config

Comment: Thank you, I went through and did exactly this. I've managed to take the old data from into a new blank site